# Is there a way to use the everything() function but make it not include everything?

Tags: r

I've got a dataframe that somewhat resembles the one below. I'm trying to plot the combination of values across the rows. I've done all that correctly, but my issue is NA values. Every row in my dataframe contains at least 1 NA value, so using na.omit isn't possible.

```
df <- df %>% unite(combined, everything(!NA), sep = "_")
count_data <- df %>%count(combined)
ggplot(count_data, aes(y = fct_reorder(combined, n), x = n)) +geom_bar(stat = "identity") +labs(title = "Row Counts by Combination of Variables", y = "Combination", x = "Count")
```

| a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | NA |
| NA | 2 | 4 | 5 |
| NA | NA | NA | 6 |
| 5 | 7 | NA | NA |

I've tried everything(!NA) but that doesn't work. I don't get errors but it just plots the counts, rather than the combined variable counts. I'm also open to not using the everything() function!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tidyselect::everything()` and `tidy-select` in general are for specifying a set a variables in a frame (i.e. columns).

Though `tidyr:unite()` knows about `na.rm`:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tidyr)

df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~a, ~b, ~c, ~d,
  1L, 2L, 3L, NA,
  NA, 2L, 4L, 5L,
  NA, NA, NA, 6L,
  5L, 7L, NA, NA,
  NA, NA, NA, NA
)

df %>% 
  # remove all-NA rows
  filter(!if_all(everything(), is.na)) %>% 
  unite(combined, everything(), sep = "_", na.rm = TRUE)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 1
#>   combined
#>   <chr>   
#> 1 1_2_3   
#> 2 2_4_5   
#> 3 6       
#> 4 5_7
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! This mainly solves my issue. However, for some reason, it doesn't remove any rows that are entirely NAs or rows that start with NA. Any ideas?

Comment: It would be quite unexpected if `unite()` would not return the same number of rows as 
 was passed to input, normally you would use it to add a column to an existing frame, so input and output lengths should always match. You can remove all-NA rows by filtering , I updated answer to show how. But I'm not sure where this removal of rows that start with NA comes from. If you do need it, please edit your question accordingly and include expected result table that matches your provided input.